# Is it possible to declare an empty form group then add form controls afterwards inside the onInit function?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

As title, how can I declare an empty form group then add form controls afterward?
I tried passed in a null or not passing anything at all, its just won't let me do it.

```
this.demoForm = new FormGroup(null);//DON'T WORK
```

Any work around? Thankyou.

Comment: `FormArray` can be the solution

Comment: try new FormGroup({}), but it would be untyped in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new empty FormGroup

```
const formGroup = new FormGroup({});
```

and then add a new `FormControl`/`FormGroup`/`FormArray` (to be precise `AbstractControl`, which is the base class of these three)

```
const formControl = new FormControl();
formGroup.addControl('controlName', formControl);
```

For more information you can find the `addControl` documentation here: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#addcontrol